# Dynamically created textbox c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I create textbox dynamically, but can't retrieve a value from created textbox. Anyone can explain to me what am I doing wrong?

```
HtmlGenericControl testes = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    testes.ID = "Div_Cabos_Rede";
    testes.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-12 letra");
    testes.InnerHtml = "Cabos de rede";
    TextBox Cabos_de_rede = new TextBox();
    Cabos_de_rede.ID = "Txt_Cabos_Rede";
    Cabos_de_rede.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-12 form-control");
    testes.InnerHtml = "Cabos de rede";
    Body.Controls.Add(testes);
    Body.Controls.Add(Cabos_de_rede);
```

This works fine almost fine (minor unrelated css problems), but when later I try to retrieve data from dynamically created textbox I get NULL value.

Here is my code to retrieve value:

```
 TextBox testar = (TextBox)Body.FindControl("Txt_Cabos_Rede");
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + testar + "');", true);
```

Comment: This seems like a *very* odd way of doing this in the first place.  Why are you dynamically creating this control?  I suspect there's a more standard way to implement whatever you're implementing.  As for getting the resulting value, perhaps you don't want to use `FindControl()` but instead just inspect the raw form data in the `Request` object?  (Side note: You're also trying to output the `TextBox` object *itself*, not it's `.Text` property.)

Comment: I need to create the control dynamically because I have an XML with different number of rows and I want to create bootstrap modal dynamically

Comment: Well, I still suspect there's a better way, but I'll defer to the design if that's what you find appropriate.  In any event, if `FindControl()` isn't working, can you debug into the control hierarchy in `Body` and see if your dynamically created controls are there at all?  If this is a post-back they might not be.  However, any form values should still be in that HTML POST request.  Are the key/value pairs you're looking for in `Request.Form`?  It's a more manual way to get the values, but manual seems to be the approach here.

Comment: My dynamically created controls appear fine, I can see them when I run my application, I suspect that the problem is with the "runat=server" tag , but i am not sure

Comment: because those controls should be created on pre-render event (at leats what the google say) and i create them on button click

Comment: I also suspect there is a better way to do it, but unfortunately, my knowledge seems to be quite limited xD

Comment: You're claiming that the resulting HTML renders correctly on the page.  So if that's the case then the form being posted to the server would contain the key/value pairs for those form elements.  Regardless of whether or not the server-side form structure is built, the data is physically there.  Again, look at the `Request` object for the posted form values.

Comment: I tried Request and it seems to work fine. Thank you very much, I guess you solved my problem. and thank you for your time. Have a nice day !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem dealing with ***dynamically created control*** is you need to reload them back in either ***Page Init*** or ***Page Load*** event.

***FYI:*** We normally use either Panel or PlaceHolder to load controls instead of Body tag, so that we can style them easily.

### ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
        <br />
        Posted Value:
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ResultLabel" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl testes = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
        testes.ID = "Div_Cabos_Rede";
        testes.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-12 letra");
        testes.InnerHtml = "Cabos de rede";
        TextBox Cabos_de_rede = new TextBox();
        Cabos_de_rede.ID = "Txt_Cabos_Rede";
        Cabos_de_rede.Attributes.Add("class", "col-md-12 form-control");
        testes.InnerHtml = "Cabos de rede";
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(testes);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Cabos_de_rede);
    }

    protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox testar = FindControlRecursive(PlaceHolder1, "Txt_Cabos_Rede") as TextBox;
        ResultLabel.Text = testar.Text;
    }

    // Custom method to search a control recursively 
    // in case it is nested inside other control. 
    // You can create it as an extension method if you would like.
    public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
    {
        if (root.ID == id)
            return root;

        return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
            .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
    }
}
```

*I know you have a lot of questions. Before commenting on this question, please create a new project, and make this very simple code to work.*

Comment: This worked fine thank you very much. not quite understood how the  FindControlRecursive method works, but I got the idea. Thank you very much